# What is nextTick and what does it do in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I read [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick), but I still can't understand it.

I know what `data`, `computed`, `watch`, `methods` do, but what is `nextTick()` used for in Vue.js?

Comment: The key concept to understand is that the DOM is updated *asynchronously*. When you change a value in Vue, the change is not *immediately* rendered to the DOM. Instead, Vue queues a DOM update and then, on a timer, updates the DOM. Normally, this happens so fast that it doesn't make a difference, but, at times, you need to update the rendered DOM after Vue has rendered it, which you can't immediately do in a method because the update hasn't happened yet. In those cases, you would use `nextTick`. [Documented here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue).

Comment: Complementing what @Bert said in [https://stackoverflow.com/q/47634258/9979046](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47634258/9979046) above, the nextTick() will be used in Unit Tests, when you need to check if a element exists in DOM (HTML), for example, if you get some information on a Axios request.

Comment: why do I feel like nextTick is something like `const nextTick = (callback, context) => { setTimeout(callback.bind(context), 0); };` ?

Answer (score 315):

#### It's all about Timing

[`nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) allows you to execute code *after* you have changed some data and Vue.js has updated the virtual DOM based on your data change, but *before* the browser has rendered that change on the page.

Normally, [devs use the native JavaScript function `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) to achieve similar behavior, but using `setTimeout` relinquishes control over to the browser *before* it gives control back to you (via calling your callback).

#### Example

Let's say you changed some data; Vue then updates the vDOM based on that data change (the changes are not yet rendered to the screen by the browser).

If you used `nextTick` at this point, your callback would get called immediately, and the browser would update the page after that callback finished executing.

If you instead used `setTimeout`, then the browser would have a chance to update the page, and *then* your callback would get called.

You can visualize this behavior by creating a small component like the following:
<sub>(Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpalikhe/50wL7mdz/80945/) to see it live)</sub>

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    {{ msg }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
        msg: 'One'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.msg = 'Two';

      this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.msg = 'Three';
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

Run your local server. You will see the message "Three" being displayed.

Now, replace `this.$nextTick` with `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.msg = 'Three';
}, 0);
```

Reload the browser. You will see "Two" before you see "Three".

That's because, with `setTimeout`:

1. Vue updated the vDOM to say "Two"
2. Vue gave control to the browser
3. The browser displayed "Two"
4. Callback was called
5. Vue updated the vDOM to say "Three"
6. Vue gave control to the browser
7. The browser displayed "Three"

But with `nextTick`, we skip steps 2 and 3! Instead of passing over control after the first vDOM update, Vue calls the callback *immediately*, which prevents the browser from updating until the callback is finished. In this example, that means "Two" is never actually displayed.

To understand how Vue implements this, you need to understand the concept of  the JavaScript [Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [microtasks](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).

Once you have those concepts clear(er), check the [source code for nextTick](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/util/next-tick.js).

Comment: This answer gave me so much clarity about how and when to use nexttick and when to use setTimeOut. thank you

Answer (score 23):

Next Tick basically allows you to run some code, after the vue has re-rendered the component when you have made some changes to the a reactive property (data).

```js
// modify data
vm.msg = 'Hello'
// DOM not updated yet
Vue.nextTick(function () {
   // this function is called when vue has re-rendered the component.
})
    
// usage as a promise (2.1.0+, see note below)
Vue.nextTick()
   .then(function () {
       // this function is called when vue has re-rendered the component.
    })
```

From the Vue.js Documentation:

Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

Read more about it, [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

Comment: update it how? this is what I don't undertand. if I update vm.msg then the dom is already updated because there is a new text ''hello" .. so how can I update it again? can you post a fiddle with an example pls? thanks

Comment: okay, I'll edit the answer and I'll try to explain it further.

Comment: @hidar you can use it in situations when you have to do multiple updates, but you want to explicitly render each other at different dom cycles

Comment: It's not for allowing you to _update_ the DOM per se, but to do anything with it (be it update, read info from it, etc) after it has been affected/modified by changes done by Vue (because you changed a reactive property value, etc).

Comment: That was an example to make it simpler.

Answer (score 12):

To make Pranshat's answer about the difference between using `nextTick` and `setTimeout`, more explicit, I have forked his fiddle:
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/wtoalabi/g7kL9Lu1/)

```js
mounted() {    
  this.one = "One";
     
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.two = "Two"
  }, 0);
      
  //this.$nextTick(()=>{
  //  this.two = "Two"
  //})}
}
```

You can see in the fiddle that when using `setTimeOut`, the initial data flashes very briefly once the component gets mounted before adapting the change. Whereas, when using `nextTick`, the data is hijacked, changed, before rendering to the browser. So, the browser shows the updated data without even any knowledge of the old.
Hope that clears the two concepts in one swoop.

Answer (score 3):

> I have created a useful demo in what scenario we can use nextTick in Vuejs, if you want update or run something immediately after your DOM updates, see addMessage function where i am calling another function in which i am using a nextTick function to update scroll to see latest message.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CDN VUE 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
        <div ref="scrolledList" style="height: 100px; width: 150px; border:1px solid red; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 5px;">
           <ul ref="scrolledHeight" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
               <li v-for="msg in messages">
                   {{msg}}
               </li>               
           </ul>
        </div>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Add Message" v-model="message" />
           <button @click="addMessage" @keyup.enter="addMessage"> Add Message</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        <script>
            Vue.createApp({
                data() {
                    return {
                       message: '',
                       messages: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
                    }
                },
                mounted() {
                    this.updateScrollNextTick()
                },
                methods: {
                    addMessage() {
                        if(this.message == ''){
                            return
                        }
                        this.messages.push(this.message)
                        this.message = ""
                        this.updateScrollNextTick()
                    },
                    updateScrollNextTick () {
                        this.$nextTick( () => {
                            let scrolledHeight = this.$refs.scrolledHeight.clientHeight
                            this.$refs.scrolledList.scrollTo({
                                behavior: 'smooth',
                                top: scrolledHeight
                            })
                        })
                    }
                },
            })
            .mount("#app")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1-**nextTick()** comes at first render of page, and every other
> Re-render after that. **onUpdated()** wont call on first Render but
> every Re-render after that (every update).

> 2- **nextTick()** comes before **onUpdated()** and also before
> **onBeforeUpdate()**