# Cannot scrollIntoView in vue onMounted hook

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, lifecycle-hook

I have a `msgHTMLElement` that is reactive based on an array ref. The `scrollIntoView` works as expected when watching the `ref.value`. As the array is updated, the HTML element representing the data updates and scrolls to the bottom as expected . .

```
const msgHTMLElement = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
watch(messages.value, () => {
    nextTick(() => {
        msgHTMLElement.value?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end"})
    })
    console.log('messages upddated')
})
```

However, I can't get the list to scroll to the bottom when the element is mounted.

So this works fine as a test

```
onMounted(() => {  
  if(msgHTMLElement.value)  {
    msgHTMLElement.value.innerHTML = 'blah';
  }
}
```

But then this doesn't (list is mounted scrolled to the top)

```
onMounted(() => {        
    msgHTMLElement.value?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});      
}
```

How can I scroll the list to the bottom when the component is mounted?

Comment: seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485725/3995261 Have you tried `this.$nextTick`?