# Weird behaviour of methods in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have one `data` variable in my app, It is `message`, And also I have one method in methods which performs some cryptographic algorithms.
Here is my code.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    message: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.message = "Hello";
      console.log("this.message ", this.message); // Prints "Hello"

      // takes around 8 seconds
      var encryptedPassphrase = generateKeystore();
      console.log("this.message ", this.message); // Prints "Hello"
    }
  }
};
```

Above `message` variable I'm displaying in HTML tag, And method `click` gets called from Vuetify button.
Below is HTML code,

```
<div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <v-btn @click="click">Click</v-btn>
</div>
```

**Issue**
Now Problem is When `click` method is called first task it does is updates `message` variable, But this `message` variable update reflects in HTML after the full function execution is completed. So In `click` function next task is cryptographic computation which takes around 8 seconds, After this completes `message` reflects in HTML. I have no idea what is going on here.
Just mentioning I'm using `webpack` here.

## Update

```
  <v-btn @click="update(); click();">Click</v-btn>
```

Even this doesn't work, Here `update` method updates `message` variable, It updates after `click` function is completed.

Comment: Do you have any reproducible or verifiable example/fiddle we can tinker with?

Comment: I can, But Issue is I can't run that cryptographic function in fiddle which takes more time to execute. :(

Comment: Maybe try wrapping the cryptographic function inside a Promise and execute it asynchronously.

Comment: Didn't work, It updates after the method execution is completely completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the message data field that's changed in the click method to reflect in the html before the method is complete, you have to wrap the cryptographic function in a `Vue.nextTick`. That will ensure that the logic inside the `nextTick` will execute on the next `DOM` update cycle. This will allow the `DOM` to be updated with the latest value for message and then it will execute the cryptographic function. Otherwise, `Vue` will wait for the click function to complete prior to the changes being reflected in the `DOM`.

`Vue.nextTick(function() { //cryptographic function })`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

Comment: It doesn't work, [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636157) `nextTick` is not the use case for this, `nextTick` is used when you update a variable before it renders in the browser, It executes some task in `nextTick` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, in the case, you should use [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for intensive tasks such as your `generateKeystore` function. The reason your `message` didn't get rendered is that only one piece of Javascript ever executing at a time, basically your `generateKeystore` blocks the Vue rendering (watcher etc) until it finishes.

I've created a js fiddle to demonstrate the Vue - Web Worker usage https://jsfiddle.net/Fourzero/t9L1g2hj/17/. You can also find the code below. In this example, the `click` handler has the same problem your described (changed message won't render until slow function is done), the `click2` method handles it in a way that the `message` 'hello' get rendered immediately, and the slow function starts executing (takes a few seconds) and will return value once finished.

### Html

```
<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">

  // This script won't be parsed by JS engines because its type is javascript/worker.
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('slow function started execution inside worker with parameter: ', e.data)
    // execute slow function
    var sum = 1;
        for (let i = 1; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    console.log('DONE!!slow function finished inside worker with result: ' + sum)
    self.postMessage(sum);
  };

</script>


<div id="app">
    <p ref="message">{{message}}</p>
    <p >slowFunctionResult: {{slowFunctionResult}}</p>
    <button @click="click">Click</button>
    <button @click="click2">Click (Run in worker)</button>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var blob = new Blob([
  document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent
], { type: "text/javascript" })

// Note: window.webkitURL.createObjectURL() in Chrome 10+.
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'xx',
    slowFunctionResult: ''
  },

  methods: {
    click() {
      this.message = 'hello';
      console.log("slow function start")
      this.slowFunction();
      console.log("slow function done")

      // the next tick won't happen until the slow function finished
    },

    click2() {
      this.message = 'hello';

      let that = this;
      worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log("Received result from worker!: " + e.data);
        that.slowFunctionResult = e.data;
      }
      // DOM should be updated before the slow function execution finished
      worker.postMessage(this.message); // Start the worker.
    },


    slowFunction() {
        var sum = 1;
        for (let i = 1; i < 10000000000; i++) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Console output of clicking the `Click (Run in worker)` button

```
slow function started execution inside worker with parameter:  hello
// after a few seconds
DONE!!slow function finished inside worker with result: 49999999990067860000
Received result from worker!: 49999999990067860000
```