# Wait for component rendering in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

### Problem in a nutshell

I'm trying to get access to some sort of `onRendered` lifecycle hook.

### What I found out about it

Analogous question: [Vue $nextTick in mounted() hook doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065810/vue-nexttick-in-mounted-hook-doesnt-work-as-expected)

The reasoning made here is: for efficiency reasons, Vue does not directly render reactive changes but internally collects the changes and once per tick renders the last 'state'. However, one can wait for the next tick, before making further changes through the use of `nextTick`.

The user uses the `onMounted` lifecycle hook, to be sure that the component has been mounted, then he makes changes to the style, then waits for the next tick, to be sure that the changes are rendered before making any more.
What happens, however, is that the last 'state' is rendered directly.

*You might think that changes happen so fast that it is not noticeable, but if it were, the CSS transition would be triggered.*

**Proposed solution**: instead of waiting for the next tick, create an imperceptible delay (even 0ms) after applying the first style. This *seems* to work.

### My reasoning

In the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick), it says `nextTick` is responsible for **reactive state** changes, but in this case, these are styles and this should be a direct manipulation of the DOM, which Vue shouldn't catch... or can it?

Regarding `onMounted` lifecycle hook [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted), although it is not *guaranteed* that the component is rendered, is written:

> This hook is typically used for performing side effects that need access to the component's **rendered** DOM ...

For these reasons, I would expect any changes to a style, within `onMounted`, to be immediately rendered and consequently trigger the CSS transition, which does not happen.

Here is a [SFC Playground Demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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), where the problem and the "solution" are presented. `App.vue` contains only the logic to reload the component, without reloading the page.

I am not convinced of the solution presented because it relies on the page being loaded or the elements being rendered in a short and hardware-based time. I'm afraid that it could cause problems with heavy loads, furthermore there is a sort of race condition: putting delay around 0ms does not guarantee the expected behavior in 100% of page loads.

I'm looking for a solution (or workaround at most) that doesn't rely on probability. Furthermore, I would like to delve deeper into the reasons for the behaviors mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a good explanation about nextTick() vs. setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636157/6225326).

I think between the two, `setTimeout()` would actully be what you want. If you're looking for a more confident solution to your problem, take a completely different approach and use Vue's built-in [Transition](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html) component

```html
<Transition name="slide" appear>
  <div ref="blockRef" class="block"></div>
</Transition>
```

The `appear` property will start the transition on initial render.

The CSS for your slide transition is then:

```css
.block {
    ...
    top: 26vh  /* transition end state */
}

.slide-enter-active {
    transition: top 3s linear 0s
}
.slide-enter-from {
    top: 0
}
.slide-enter-to {
    top: 26vh
}
```

Once you have the transition working on mount, remounting the component will effectively restart it. Changing [key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html) is a good way to force this.

**App.vue**

```js
const myRef = ref(true);
async function restart() {
  myRef.value = !myRef.value
}
```

```html
<button @click="restart">Restart</button>
<Comp :key="String(myRef)" />
```

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks! I had also thought about a possible implementation with `Transition`, unfortunately I don't know how to achieve it in my case because the element changes position several times and I would like to be able to set it in a more declarative way. It is possible to leverage `Transition` or should I use `setTimeout` ?