# Waiting for the DOM to update in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuejs3

In order to get an animation to work, I am trying to update data in a method consecutively, but the updates are happening to fast.

The element in question was previously animated by setting a custom property `--int-menu-height` to a height, retrieved via a `$ref`. A `transitionend` event is then setting that variable to `auto`. Now to get the same transition into the other direction, I need to *first* remove the auto and replace it with an interpolatable value, and *then* set it to zero, so that it animates between those two values. There is another `transitionend` event waiting, to finish the entire interaction. This is what my code for the closing looks like, right now:

```
const comp = this;
const menu = this.$refs.menu;
const menuHeight = this.$refs.menuHeight.clientHeight+'px';

// set it too the actual height (from previously 'auto')
this.menuStyles = { '--int-menu-height': menuHeight };
this.$nextTick( () => {
    // set it to zero, so that it animates
    this.menuStyles = { '--int-menu-height': 0 } 
});

// never firing, because no transition
menu.addEventListener('transitionend', function closeMenu() {
    comp.isMenuOpen = false;
    menu.removeEventListener('transitionend', closeMenu);
});
```

I'm thought that `$nextTick()` would do the trick, but it is still happening to fast. How can I update `this.menuStyles` *only* after making sure that the previous update has fully rendered through?

Comment: Instead of creating your custom listeners, Why don't you utilize the transitions API of vue ? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: @JimishFotariya It cannot be utilised in my specific instance. At the moment, I am not looking for a solution to my animation, I am rather looking for help with my specific code.

Comment: Maybe it's because **$nextTick()** not working as you expect, read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634258/what-is-nexttick-and-what-does-it-do-in-vue-js

Comment: Try to use `setTimeout` instead `$nextTick()`

Comment: Oh dear, now I feel really dumb. But of course, that made it all work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like [Radeanu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724281/waiting-for-the-dom-to-update-in-vue?noredirect=1#comment123245241_69724281) pointed out, I can just use `setTimeout()`. Because `$nextTick()` fires after an update in the virtual DOM, not in the real DOM. The code that I use now, that works, looks like this:

```js
setTimeout( () => {
    // set it to zero, so that it animates
    this.menuStyles = { '--int-menu-height': 0 } 
}, 1);
```