# Vue.js and Render Scheduling in Different Environments

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, vuejs3, html-rendering

I am interested in understanding if and why a specific environment / implementation generates this type of race condition. I chose the implementation shown below after studying these cases:

- [What is nextTick and what does it do in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634258/what-is-nexttick-and-what-does-it-do-in-vue-js/47636157#47636157)
- [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

### My Scenario

I am creating a complex transition on a Vue component appearing. The basic idea is to wait for the component to be mounted by using the `onMounted` lifecycle hook, then, put the various changes in the task queue via `setTimeout`. This way, the browser will have a chance to render the element with the default style, before applying any new styles.

```js
<script setup>

// ...

onMounted(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // All style manipulation logic
    }, 0);
});

</script>
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) exposing the situation (The logic is fully inside `Comp.vue`).

This works in my local environment, however it has unexpected behavior in the Vue SFC Playground (where the animation does not occur when the page loads). So I am concerned that this type of approach is tightly bound to the runtime environment and severely affects the reusability of my component.

### Transitions ?

Vue uses a built-in component `Transition`, to predictably manage the effects associated with the appearance of a component. However, in my case, I'd like to have a more imperative approach on my component and that isn't just limited to appearance. Here is an example:

```js
// Inside myComp's parent
onMounted(() => {
  myComp.doSomething();
});
```

The problem here is that the parent can't know whether the rendering or transition has already happened

The most elegant solution I thought of is to expose a `Promise` inside `myComp`, which is resolved by a `Transition` hook on the component appearing. Then `await` the `Promise` inside the parent `onMounted` hook -- would that make sense? Has some drawbacks?