Having to use setTimeout even after awaiting nextTick?
I am trying to watch a computed value that gets filled up with messages from a store. This is it (code reduced for brevity):
<div ref="RefWindow">
 <ul v-for="Message in Feed">
   <li>Message</li>
  </ul>
</div>


const Feed = computed(() => MyStore.Messages)
const RefWindow = ref();

function scrollToBottom() {
      console.log(`scrollTop: ${RefWindow.value.scrollTop}, scrollHeight: ${RefWindow.value.scrollHeight}`)
      RefWindow.value.scrollTop = RefWindow.value.scrollHeight; // Scrolls to bottom
    }

 watch(() => Feed, async () => {
      await nextTick();
    
      scrollToBottom(); // Doesn't work console.log shows scrollTop: 0, scrollHeight: 0
 
      setTimeout(()=> scrollToBottom(), 20); // Works console.log shows scrollTop: 0, scrollHeight: 4203
      }
    }, {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true
    })

It was my understanding that nextTick() is almost like onUpdated lifecycle hook in that once Feed's value has changed, on the next update of the DOM the code should run. However without the setTimeout in place it seems the scrollHeight of the div RefWindow is not being updated.
What is the correct way to go about this without using a timeout?

nextTick makes sure "Feed" value was updated in a view, in case it's used there. It's unknown how the value affects the content. E.g. if you use v-for this won't work. The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Currently there's not enough info to reproduce the problem

@EstusFlask Yes the template uses a v-for. I updated my example. I am sorry I didn't know how to create a test Vue app for this.

v-for works in its own way and takes a while to render. This isn't documented anywhere afaik. It would be less flaky to put code that relies on component mount to onMounted instead of immediate:true, then use await nextTick() there. Also flush:post can help for updates like suggested below. Consider providing a workable demo at stackblitz or sfc.vuejs.org if you need aid with debugging it.

@EstusFlask thanks I've solved it by moving the watch code to onUpdated hook

@EstusFlask and for anyone else coming here, the answer lies here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634258/what-is-nexttick-and-what-does-it-do-in-vue-js

Just use a directive:
Playground
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
setTimeout(() => {
  Feed.value = Array.from({length: 100});
}, 1000)
const Feed = ref([]);
const RefWindow = ref();

const vScroll = (el, {value}) => {
  if(!value) return;
  console.log(`scrollTop: ${RefWindow.value.scrollTop}, scrollHeight: ${RefWindow.value.scrollHeight}`)
  RefWindow.value.scrollTop = RefWindow.value.scrollHeight; // Scrolls to bottom
};
</script>
<template>
  <div ref="RefWindow" style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid gray;padding: 10px; overflow: auto">
 <ul v-for="(Message, idx) in Feed">
   <li v-scroll="idx===Feed.length -1">Message</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

